# Получение пути до загруженного файла Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, img, path

Загрузил картинку через форму на локалхост

```
    $file = $request->file('preview');
    $path = $file->store('previews', 'public');
```

Она находится в папке `/storage/app/public/previews/<image_name>.jpeg`

**Как мне вставить ее через тег `<img>`?**

Я пробовал:

`<img src="{{ Storage::path('public/previews/<image_name>')}}" alt="">`

И:

`<img src="{{storage_path('app/public/previews/<image_name>')}}" alt="">`

В этих случая в консоли появляется ошибка

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/OpenServer/OSPanel/domains/localhost/storage/app/public/previews/yOWdI1HrI0dOeNEzuPfBa4SwUfJMPU0aQuLOQFLL.jpeg
```

Comment: Не storage_path, а [Storage::url](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. нужна ссылка из public на storage `php artisan storage:link`
2. для ссылки использовать `Storage::url('public/previews/<image_name>')`